# Block to block operations between 2 dask arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dask

Good day friends, I have a question about `map_blocks()`. I'm trying something simple, I want to take the dot product between columns (the blocks) of 2 arrays like so:

```py
    x=da.random.random((100,5), chunks=(100,1))
    y=da.random.random((100,5), chunks=(100,1))
    
    def block_dot_product(a, b):
        out=np.dot(a,b)
        return out
    
    result=da.map_blocks(block_dot_product, x, y,dtype=np.float64).compute()
```

If this works as expected it should return a single float for the dot product of each block. So, output should be a single 1x5 array.

I'm clearly missing something because this raises the exception `ValueError: shapes (100,1) and (100,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 100 (dim 0)`

Any pointers as to what I'm not understanding???

Comment: [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) expects the last axis of a and the second-to-last (e.g. the first in this case) axis of b to be the same length. change your function to `out=np.dot(a.T, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: this question was resolved in Slack, https://dask.slack.com/archives/C02282J3Q6Q/p1639506482143700

One way to resolve this (as per Slack) is to use `np.squeeze` to make sure that the computed dimensions match the expected dimensions.